# Adding multiple component inside AppComponent in agular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am wondering is it possible to add multiple components like Component1 , Cmponent2 inside AppComponent like below code but it seems not working am i missing anything ?(ignore this so complaining  )ajxbajcbjascjajcabcajbcbajbcajbcjbascbjajbcjacbacjajcacbacbjabcajbcbjabcjajbcabjcjbacbjajbcbajcbjajbcabjcajbcbacbjajbcbjacbjabjcbjacbjajbcajbcbjacbjajbcbjabjcbjacbja

```
import { Component,Directive,ElementRef, APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
        <second-component>
           test second
        </second-component>
        <third-component>
           test third
        </third-component>


    `,
    styles: [`

    `]
})
export class AppComponent {


}

@Component({
  selector: 'second-componet',
  template: `
        <h1>
           test
        </h1>
    `,
    styles: [`

    `]
})


export class SecondCompoent{

}

@Component({
  selector: 'third-componet',
  template: `
        <h1>
           test
        </h1>
    `,
    styles: [`

    `]
})


export class ThirdCompoent{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to show the text appearing inside **component tags** to appear in the app-component. This is called **content-projection** and you can achieve this using the **ng-content**. Modify your code like this

```js
import { Component,Directive,ElementRef, APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
        <second-component>
           test second
        </second-component>
        <third-component>
           test third
        </third-component>


    `,
    styles: [`

    `]
})
export class AppComponent {


}

@Component({
  selector: 'second-componet',
  template: `
        <h1>
           test
        </h1>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    `,
    styles: [`

    `]
})


export class SecondCompoent{

}

@Component({
  selector: 'third-componet',
  template: `
        <h1>
           test
        </h1>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    `,
    styles: [`

    `]
})


export class ThirdCompoent{

}
```

Note the addition of **ng-content** in the templates of SecondComponent and ThirdComponent.

Please find a sample [stack-blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1pc8t6)

For a more detailed discussion of ng-content [check this](https://medium.com/@joshblf/wtf-is-ng-content-8382b2a664e1).

Thanks.

Comment: I am getting below error when i am running on stckbliz Error in /turbo_modules/@angular/compiler@8.0.0/bundles/compiler.umd.js (2479:21)
Template parse errors:
'second-component' is not a known element:
1. If 'second-component' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'second-component' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. (" [ERROR ->]<second-component>

Comment: Where are you getting this error? My stack-blitz code is running fine. This error simply means that second-component is not declared in your module. Simply add into the imports array of your module.

Comment: Becoz you have declared Components in app.module i dont want to declare componets in app.module i want to do that dynamically from app.component.ts

Comment: can you add second-component and third-component in your  html if its working

Comment: A component must be declared in the module, before it can be used. If you want to dynamically load a component, refer this link

https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/dynamically-add-components-to-the-dom-with-angular-71b0cb535286

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible. You have a Typo in your selectors, look at `selector: 'second-componet',` and `selector: 'third-componet',`